# Why cant the terminal locate and install Acetoneiso_2.3.tar.gz.?

Tags: 12.04, apt

The package is on my desktop

```
cd Desktop
parallels@LouiseAvon:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install acetoneiso_2.3.tar.gz
[sudo] password for parallels: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package acetoneiso_2.3.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'acetoneiso_2.3.tar.gz'
parallels@LouiseAvon:~/Desktop$
```

What can I do? Is the file extension the problem?

Comment: If you open that archive you'll see it's just the sources. You'll need to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get is for packages that are resident in the Ubuntu on-line repositories. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install acetoneiso
```

A tar.gz file is only needed when you wish to compile a package not found in the repositories from source code.